# Unable to import Django Project onto additional computers

Tags: django, github, pycharm

For the final project in my software class, my group has decided to use Django to build a web app. I created a Django project with a working Virtual Environment and have it sitting in GitHub for my teammates to be able to access and collaborate. So far, I have been able to run the website and create new apps with ease. That being said, when my teammates first pull from VCS into Pycharm Professional and configure the interpreter, they are met with this error:

```
Cannot set up a python SDK
at Python 3.8 (DeliverMe)
(/Users/taylorschissel/PycharmProjects/DeliverMe/venv/bin/python)
The SDK seems invalid.
```

I have read through many posts but cannot seem to find anyone with a similar issue, so I am at a loss for causes/solutions.

Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/isaacfc4/DeliverMe

Comment: Try removing the .idea and venv directories and getting your teammates to recreate the venv locally

Comment: I agree with @IainShelvington but remove db as well

Comment: Okay will do. We are all new to Django, but I was under the impression that venv was designed specifically to solve the problem of everyone having to install packages locally.